# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'types.GenericAlias' and 'int'

Tags: python, compiler-errors, computer-science

```py
my_list = [
    1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10,
    11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
    21, 22, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 47, 48, 49, 50
]

# binary search for list of number.

def binary_search(my_list, users_input):
    low = 0
    high = len(my_list)-1
    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        guess = list[mid]
        if guess == users_input:
            return mid
        if guess < users_input:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1
    return None 

# checking if you input is equal to binary input.

def guess_the_number():
    while True:
        users_position = int(input("Enter the position in the list of number, which you wanted: "))
        if users_position == input_binary_search:
            print("Good job! According to binary search you have guessed correct!")
            break 
        elif users_position < input_binary_search:
            print("Your position number is less than the position expected by the binary search")
        else:
            print("Your position number is bigger than the position expected by the binary search")

# input a numbers from the user and guessing the position of the number in the list.

print("Welcome. It's my mini game. "
      "Your tasks is:\nInput the number from list"
      "\nGuess the position of this number in this list.")
print(my_list)

users_input = int(input("Enter the number from this list: "))
input_binary_search = binary_search(my_list, users_input)
guess_the_number()
```

I don't know why `"'\<=' not supported between instances of 'types.GenericAlias' and 'int'"` and how to solve the error? I was trying to rename variables but it didn't help. I'm a beginner in python so I understand that code is bad, but i really want to get to know what is problem.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I think you meant to write: `guess = my_list[mid]`.

Comment: On line 16 you have `guess = list[mid]`, `list` is the type name.